# pass data when clicking the cell in mvvm

Tags: ios, mvvm

I need to select the cell from tableview and my code as below:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    let vc = OfferDetailViewController(nibName: "OfferDetailViewController", bundle: nil)
    let indexPath = (self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow)!
    let offerViewModel1 = self.offerViewModel.sourceAt(index: indexPath.row)
    vc.offerViewModel2 = offerViewModel1
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

I am doing in the mvvm method. I have two screens.

1. listing the data in the tableview
2. on selecting the cell from tableview, it must go to other screen. It contains the details.

I have done to list the data. But on clicking I need to pass he pass. How to do?
I can't understanding did it should pass to viewmodel or viewcontroller.

foodviewmodel:-

```
class foodViewModel: NSObject {

    var datasourceModel:foodDataSource

    init(withdatasource  offerDatasourceModel: foodDataSource) {
        datasourceModel = offerDatasourceModel
    }


    func datafordisplay(atindex indexPath: IndexPath) -> foodModel{
        return  datasourceModel.dataListArray![indexPath.row]

    }


   func numberOfRowsInSection(section:Int) -> Int {

      return (datasourceModel.dataListArray?.count)!
  }


    //indexpath.....
   // func sourceAt(atindex indexPath: IndexPath) -> foodModel {
      //  return self.datasourceModel.dataListArray![indexPath.row]
   // }

    func sourceAt(index :Int) -> foodModel  {
        return self.datasourceModel.dataListArray![index]
    }
}
```

foodDataSource .swift:-

```
  var dataListArray:Array<foodModel>? = []


    init(array :Array<[String:Any]>?) {
        super.init()
        var newArray:Array<[String:Any]> = []
        if array == nil{

            newArray = self.getJsonDataStored4()
        }
        else{
            newArray = array!

        }

        var datalist:Array<foodModel> = []
        for dict in newArray{

            let model = foodModel(dictionary: dict)

            datalist.append(model!)
        }
        self.dataListArray = datalist
    }



}

typealias dummyDataSource4 = foodDataSource
extension dummyDataSource4{

    func getJsonDataStored4() ->Array<Dictionary<String,String>>{

        let jsonArray = [["id":"1","name":"Lunch Buffet","price":"Q28","location":"Doha, Qatar","imageurl":"","offertype":"Today's Offer","restaurtantname":"MOMS KITCHEN"],["id":"2","name":"Economy Meal","price":"Q65","location":"Doha, Qatar","imageurl":"","offertype":"Tomorrow's Offer","restaurtantname":"Mr.Shawarma"],["id":"3","name":"Sit-Down Buffet","price":"Q65","location":"Doha, Qatar","imageurl":"","offertype":"Weekend's Offer","restaurtantname":"Maharaja Darbar"],["id":"4","name":"Lunch Buffet","price":"Q28","location":"Doha, Qatar","imageurl":"","offertype":"Today's Offer","restaurtantname":"Shircz Garden"]] as Array<Dictionary<String,String>>

        return jsonArray
    }


    Then i created fooddetailmodel,fooddetaildatasource,fooddetailviewmodel classes.
```

But i don't know what to pass

i have given the code:-

```
var offerViewModel2 :QM_OfferModel!
```

//  @IBOutlet private weak var tableView: UITableView!

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

 }
```

Comment: 1) please show your OfferDetailViewController code and your ViewModel code
2) What's happening when you tap on cell now?

Comment: @AntonNovoselov i have added the code .please check....

Comment: how to solve the problem

Comment: and what's the code of OfferDetailViewController?